# How to share a poll to a whatsapp group from my app?

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

I want to share a poll with a question and 4 options to a whatsapp group from my Android app share button. How to do that in Android using java or kotlin ?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, so that we can help you solve your Problem...